# Docker Desktop en Windows es muy lento

Tags: docker, rendimiento

Esto utilizando **Docker Desktop** en Windows y es muy lento, las páginas tardan demasiado en cargar en el navegador, se supone que estoy trabajando con WSL2 y que debería ser mas rápido, y por tener estas opción habilitada no me permite cambiar la cantidad de CPU o Memoria a asiganar.

Comment: Primero mencionas Docker Desktop y luego WSL2. Creo que deberías considerar editar tu pregunta para explicar un poco mejor el problema, aunque probablemente esté no sea el sitio adecuado para tu pregunta, pues no parece tener mucha relación con la programación.

Comment: Hola y gracias por comentar. Si conoces de Docker Desktop para Windows, sabes que trabaja con Windows Subsystem Linux 2 **WSL2** para mejorar el rendimiento, dejando atras a HyperV, por lo cuál la pregunta es completamente válida, ya que logro obtener un buen performance de mi ambiente para correr mis apps. Me imagino que alguíen ya resolvió este inconveniente.

Comment: Una enorme disculpa, cuando yo utilizaba Docker en Windows no existía WSL2 y por ende no hacían uso de él, adicionalmente dejé de utilizarlo en Windows por lo que desconocía ese uso, aunque eso es otra historia. Tampoco dije que tu pregunta no fuera válida, simplemente que parece no tener relación directa con la programación (parece ser más un problema de configuración) por lo que este sitio puede no ser el más adecuado para encontrar una solución. Tal vez puedas encontrar una solución o al menos más ayuda en [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Agradezco de nuevo tu comentario, intentare buscar solución en el sitio recomendado. Feliz día.

Answer (score 1):

**Puedes probar realizando las siguientes acciones:**

- Acceder a: **Configuración / actualización y seguridad / seguridad de windows / abrir seguridad de Windows / protección contra virus y amenazas / administrar la configuración / agregar o quitar exclusiones**. Una vez ahí, excluye la carpeta de sistema de *Docker* `C:\Program Files\Docker` y las carpetas de tus proyecto ligadas a *Docker*.

**NOTA:** De igual forma podrías desactivar Windows defender solo para probar si hay mejora antes de hacer todo lo anterior. En mi caso si la hubo.

Con esto notarás algo de diferencia, pero aún así no se compara a la ejecución en un sistema **Linux** o **MacOS** que también funciona bien.